# Can't install zc.buildout with zc.recipe.egg with Python 3.6 or higher

Tags: python, python-3.x, buildout

I'm using zc.buildout (with zc.recipe.egg) since a long time to build my Python packages and deploy my running environments.

Since a few days, I can't use it anymore with any Python version higher to 3.5!  :(

On startup, I receive an error (here in a Gitlab-CI job):

```
$ pip install zc.buildout
Collecting zc.buildout
  Downloading zc.buildout-2.13.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (153 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=8.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from zc.buildout) (52.0.0)
Installing collected packages: zc.buildout
Successfully installed zc.buildout-2.13.3
$ buildout
Setting socket time out to 3 seconds.
Creating directory '/builds/G3v_6jyd/0/onf/support/python/pyramid/pyams-v2/pyams-security/develop-eggs'.
Develop: '/builds/G3v_6jyd/0/onf/support/python/pyramid/pyams-v2/pyams-security/.'
warning: no files found matching '*.txt'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.*~' found anywhere in distribution
Couldn't develop '/builds/G3v_6jyd/0/onf/support/python/pyramid/pyams-v2/pyams-security/../ext/lingua' (not found)
Couldn't develop '/builds/G3v_6jyd/0/onf/support/python/pyramid/pyams-v2/pyams-security/../pyams_catalog' (not found)
Couldn't develop '/builds/G3v_6jyd/0/onf/support/python/pyramid/pyams-v2/pyams-security/../pyams_file' (not found)
Couldn't develop '/builds/G3v_6jyd/0/onf/support/python/pyramid/pyams-v2/pyams-security/../pyams_i18n' (not found)
Couldn't develop '/builds/G3v_6jyd/0/onf/support/python/pyramid/pyams-v2/pyams-security/../pyams_mail' (not found)
Couldn't develop '/builds/G3v_6jyd/0/onf/support/python/pyramid/pyams-v2/pyams-security/../pyams_site' (not found)
Couldn't develop '/builds/G3v_6jyd/0/onf/support/python/pyramid/pyams-v2/pyams-security/../pyams_utils' (not found)
Getting distribution for 'zc.recipe.egg==2.0.7'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'main'
An error occurred when trying to install /tmp/tmp9eg4_d0rget_dist/zc.recipe.egg-2.0.7.tar.gz. Look above this message for any errors that were output by easy_install.
While:
  Installing.
  Getting section package.
  Initializing section package.
  Installing recipe zc.recipe.egg.
  Getting distribution for 'zc.recipe.egg==2.0.7'.
An internal error occurred due to a bug in either zc.buildout or in a
recipe being used:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 2174, in main
    getattr(buildout, command)(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 701, in install
    [self[part]['recipe'] for part in install_parts]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 701, in <listcomp>
    [self[part]['recipe'] for part in install_parts]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1324, in __getitem__
    options._initialize()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1432, in _initialize
    self.initialize()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1438, in initialize
    recipe_class = _install_and_load(reqs, 'zc.buildout', entry, buildout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1388, in _install_and_load
    allow_hosts=buildout._allow_hosts
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zc/buildout/easy_install.py", line 957, in install
    return installer.install(specs, working_set)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zc/buildout/easy_install.py", line 682, in install
    for dist in self._get_dist(requirement, ws):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zc/buildout/easy_install.py", line 574, in _get_dist
    dists = [_move_to_eggs_dir_and_compile(dist, self._dest)]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zc/buildout/easy_install.py", line 1745, in _move_to_eggs_dir_and_compile
    [tmp_loc] = glob.glob(os.path.join(tmp_dest, '*'))
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 1, got 0)
```

I actually use the last setuptools version (52.0.0), and I need to be able to build my packages for all Python versions from 3.5 to 3.9...

Any idea?

Best regards,

Thierry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same problem and believe I have found the underlying problem.

The latest `setuptools` version (52.0.0) removed `easy_install` which is used by `zc.buildout`.

See this PR for reference: https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/pull/2544

To solve (at least for now), you can explicitly install/require a previous version of `setuptools`.

Comment: That's exactl what I have done ant it's fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to Max Billingsley III's answer:

The currently last working version of `setuptools` with `zc.buildout 2.13.3` is `51.3.3`.

I created a [pull request](https://github.com/buildout/buildout/pull/545) to add this install requirement to `zc.buildout`, which - before merging - needs [another pull request](https://github.com/buildout/buildout/pull/547) to fix the broken build pipeline of `buildout`.

There is already an [alpha version](https://pypi.org/project/zc.buildout/3.0.0a2/) of `zc.buildout` which should also work - without pinning `setuptools` as it no longer uses `easy_install` but `pip`.